# .NET 2.0 Using Path.Combine with more than 2 arguments?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to combine more than 2 arguments using Path.Combine. However this doesn't work using .NET Framework 2.0. Basically,
how can I do the following:

> System.IO.Path.Combine (path1, path2, path3);

In C# using .NET framework 2.0 ?

Comment: Path.Combine(string,string) was around in 2.0 Remember that MSDN allows you to select which version of NET you want a reference for. Check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: `Path.Combine(Path.Combine(path1, path2), path3)`, but it's ugly, so just write a wrapper for it.